# Tag merge / synonym request: [srp] → [single-responsibility]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [srp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/srp) (26 questions) into [single-responsibility](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-responsibility) (27), and make them synonyms.

Preference for master tag is because I consider *single-responsibility* a more descriptive name.

---

Tag *srp* wiki excerpt is

> In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle (srp) states that every object should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

Tag *single-responsibility* doesn't have wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This task has been accomplished.